# Posifion fixing only one box of flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a few column like these.

```
<div style="display: flex;flex-direction:column">
<main class="main-contents" role="main">TopHeader </main>
<div> content A</div>
<div> content B</div>
<div> content C</div>
<div> content D</div>
</div>
```

I want to make `main` sticky (like youtube player) to the top of page and make content A~D scrollable.

Is there any good way to accomplish this??

I am afraid using `flex` is not appropriate for this purpose,

however I am making responsive web, so I want to use as same the way as possible.

Comment: Do you want to create a navbar like `stackoverflow` which remains fixed on scrolling page contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here you go...**

```css
.main-contents {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

div {
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <main class='main-contents' role='main'>TopHeader</main>
  <div style='display: flex;flex-direction:column'>
    <div>content A</div>
    <div>content B</div>
    <div>content C</div>
    <div>content D</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```